# get the width and height of NSView and NSImageView

Tags: cocoa, nsview, appkit

I have a NSView, there is a NSImageView on the NSView

in the source codes of the NSView

I wrote:

```
NSImage *image = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] autorelease];
NSImageView *newImageView = nil;
newImageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[self bounds]];
[newImageView setImage:image];
[newImageView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];
```

Is there a way to read the width and height of the NSView and NSImageView?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The size of any view (NSView, NSImageView, etc.) is `view.frame.size` or `view.bounds.size`.
In both cases it is an identical `NSSize` struct. You can write code like this:

```
NSSize size = newImageView.frame.size;
NSLog(@"size: %@", NSStringFromSize(size));
NSLog(@"size: %f x %f", size.width, size.height);
```

To change it, you need to update the view `frame` property:

```
NSRect frame = view.frame;
frame.size = NSMakeSize(<#new width#>, <#new height#>);
view.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the `- (NSRect)bounds` method.